# Rails doesn't execute javascript response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

Alright, I have a small problem with Rails and it's driving me nuts.

I have a simple_form:

```
<section id="address_form">
    <%= simple_form_for [:cockpit, @location, @address], :remote => true, :html => {:id => "location_address_#{@location.id}"} do |f| %>


      <%= f.input :latitude, :as => :hidden %>
      <%= f.input :longitude, :as => :hidden %>


      <%= f.input :gmaps, :as => :hidden %>


      <%= f.input :address_line_1, label: false, placeholder: "Address Line 1" %>
      <%= f.input :address_line_2, label: false, placeholder: "Address Line 2" %>
      <%= f.input :city, label: false, placeholder: "City" %>
      <%= f.input :state, label: false, placeholder: "State" %>
      <%= f.input :zip, label: false, placeholder: "Zip" %>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <%= f.input :country, :collection => Carmen::Country.all.map(&:name), :selected => resource.country, :include_blank => true, prompt: :Country, label: false %>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
          <%= link_to "Save", "#", :class=> "btn", :"data-blocker" => true, :"data-blocker-element" => "location_address_#{@location.id}", :"data-sendable" => true, "data-sendable-form" => "location_address_#{@location.id}" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </section>
```

Now, I kept getting a 406 Not Acceptable every time I submit the form and I didn't have the slightest clue as to why (406 is only used for invalid request types, e.g. if your controller only responds to js requests) until I checked the request in Chrome's dev tools:

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6gfC.png)

For some reason, Rails appends a dot and an ID to the URL, causing it to process the request with an invalid request format.

I went ahead and manually set the request format to js for that action:

```
class Cockpit::AddressesController < Cockpit::BaseController
  helper_method :location
  before_filter :set_format, only: [:update]
  inherit_resources

  respond_to :js, :html

  def update
    update! do |format|
      @json = location.address.reload.to_gmaps4rails
      format.js
    end
  end

  def set_format
    request.format = "js"
  end

  protected

  def location
    @location ||= Location.find(params[:location_id])
  end
end
```

Now the request processes fine and the .js.erb file is being rendered, but the Javascript code in it is not being executed. This is the response:

```
LtNoty.success("Changes saved!");
window.location.href = "/cockpit/locations/22/address";
```

This is the .js.erb file:

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
  LtNoty.error("Processing your request failed!");
<% else %>
  LtNoty.success("Changes saved!");
  window.location.href = "/cockpit/locations/<%= params[:location_id] %>/address";
<% end %>
```

If I put <% puts 'test' %> in the .js.erb file, the output shows up in my console, but the Javascript still refuses to execute.

Why?

EDIT// Relevant routes:

```
  namespace :cockpit do
    resources :locations do
      resources :tabs
      resources :pictures
      resources :location_activities
      resources :location_prices
      resource :address
      resources :reviews
    end
    resources :supports
    resources :pictures
    resources :activities
    resources :prices
    resources :requests do
      resources :responses
      match 'new/:state' => 'responses#new', :as => :new_response_state
    end

    resources :reservations

    root  :to => "home#index"
  end
```

Comment: not sure about simple_form_for, try form_for and post your config/routes file if there is still an issue

Comment: I've added all relevant routes to the OP :)

Comment: Did you run 'rake routes' and ensure that your route is in there?  (Also, shouldn't it be 'resource' instead of 'resources'?) .. From your routes file, there should be a /cockpit/locations/id/address [post] entry.  Also, did you check the html and verify the form tag?

Comment: Follow this link and see if you get any js error:http://alfajango.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/